# How to randomly generate a function that is a permutation for integers <10000

Tags: java, random, permutation

I want to allow users to use the same username, but have some extra id in the form #XXXX where X is a number (for instance, BestUserName#3421), similar to how is done on Battle.net for instance.

No two users should have the same username and #id combination.

Also, I don't want my users to be able to easily predict the extra id of other users. So, I can't just start with BestUserName#0000, then BestUserName#0001, BestUserName#0002, …).

Therefore, I want to generate, for each username, a bijection f(n) from all numbers between 0000 and 9999 to every number between 0000 and 9999. f must makes it hard to guess what f(n-1) is when you know f(n). Also, f(n) must be not be the same for all usernames.

Then the first user will be BestUserName#f(0000), the second one BestUserName#f(0001), and so on, and my users won't be able to guess each other's #id.

How can I do this in Java ?

Comment: Take the set of possible ids (0000-9999), remove the ones already in use, and select one at random?

Comment: What do you expect to gain by having a function instead of just generating a random number?

Comment: @biziclop Most likely uniqueness.  The generalized [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem) tells us that with a pool size of 10000 values, we'll have a 50/50 chance of generating duplicates by the time we've generated 118 values.  The rate of duplicate occurrences rapidly increases as we generate even more values.

Comment: @pjs It doesn't really, only the cumulative chance of generating a single duplicate rises rapidly.  After 118 values, the likelihood of the next number being a duplicate is still only `118/10000`. And if you hit the unlucky 1.1%, then you just generate another one, job done (the expected number of retries grows logarithmically as the pool fills up, so no big problems there). When this strategy becomes unwieldy is when almost the entire pool is filled, but at that point it's hardly fulfilling its original purpose of making existing usernames hard to guess.

Comment: @biziclop I was referring to the probability of duplicates existing, my premise was that OP was seeking uniqueness and I my comment was meant to point out that the probability of uniqueness rapidly declines with randomness.

Comment: If you're OK with powers of 2 (not of 10), a controlled shuffling of bits would be bijective. It can be implemented with a bunch of `&`s to isolate bits, a bunch of shifts arranged so that no two bits end up on the same position, and a bunch of `|`s to merge them back. The upside is that you don't need to store the whole permutation state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a bijection.  Encryption is a bijection, so just encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3... and as long as you use the same key there will be no repeats.  Encryption ensures that there is no obvious order in which the numbers appear.

You want an unusual range, 0000..9999 so you will probably need [Hasty Pudding cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher), which can handle many different ranges, yours included.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't been able to find a Java implementation of the Hasty Pudding cipher, and I couldn't understand how it works from the Wikipedia article, though, but I found this, which seems perfect for my purpose: https://github.com/robshep/JavaFPE .

Answer (score 5):

In your constructor, create an `ArrayList` initialized with the values `0000`-`9999`, shuffle it, and initialize a counter to -1 (or 10000).  Each time a user is added, increment (or decrement) the counter and use it to index the next element of the `ArrayList`.  Alternatively, if you're adding the extra id as an attribute of users you can ditch the counter and just remove and assign the last (or first) element of the `ArrayList`.

If the assignment is supposed to be permanent, you'll have to store the prior assignments, shuffled `ArrayList`, and counter value so you can pick up where you left off last time.

Comment: This seems a good solution but the main drawback is that I have to store a list of 10000 values for each possible username. I think I could potentially just store the random seed, no? I am not sure how costly it is to shuffle a list with a given seed.

Comment: Yes, you could just store the seed and the current location in the sequence for each username.  A [good shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) is O(n) to do permute n items, and if you implement it yourself you can shuffle only as many elements as you need.

Comment: However, I wouldn't recommend this if serious money is involved, since the seed [state space required for a PRNG to yield all possible permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#Pseudorandom_generators:_problems_involving_state_space.2C_seeding.2C_and_usage) would be larger than storing 10000 shuffled values.  I have no idea what 10000! is when expressed as a power of 2, but it's immense.

Comment: Just worked it out.  Log_2(10000!) is 118459, so you'd need something an order of magnitude larger than Mersenne Twister's gargantuan state space of 19937 bits, and no skimping on seeding it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I happen to have done a parameter search in this area and found the following 14-bit hash function:

```
int h(int x) {
    x &= 0x3fff;
    x ^= x >> 8;
    x *= 0x68ab;
    x &= 0x3fff;
    x ^= x >> 8;
    x *= 0x594b;
    x &= 0x3fff;
    x ^= x >> 8;
    return x;
}
```

This hash follows the [murmur3 mix](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.cpp#L66) function construction.  The `&=` operations are to keep the arithmetic operating in the 14-bit overflow domain, but other than that each step is a bijection, and so the overall hash is a bijection.

Every multiplication is odd (making it co-prime to the modulo 2**14, which guarantees that all results are unique), and the shift-exclusive-or operations can be reversed by unwinding the operation one bit at a time.

But the above function only guarantees to map one number less than 16384 to another number less than 16384.  We need to limit this to less than 10000.

If you wrap it in the following loop it'll be constrained to values less than 10000 (don't worry, the average number of iterations is provably 1.6384 so it's quite safe):

```
int f(int x) {
  do {
    x = h(x);
  } while (x >= 10000);
  return x;
}
```

Because the hash function inside the loop is bijective, only one input `x` can map to any given result.  If that result is out of range, but `x` was in-range, then the next iteration of the hash must map to a new value.  Even if it points to a new out-of-range value the chain must eventually be forced back in-range.

A wholly-out-of-range cycle *can* exist, but it would be unreachable from an in-range value, because the implication would be that one link in that cycle has two values that map to it (one from outside, one from inside), which cannot be achieved by a bijective function.

This implies that input to `f()` must be already in-range to be safe from an infinite loop.

Now to make it different for each username, try this:

```
int f(int x, int username_hash) {
  int m = (username_hash * 2 + 1) & 0x3fff;
  int c = (username_hash >> 13) & 0x3fff;
  do {
    x = (x * m + c) & 0x3fff;
    x = h(x);
  } while (x >= 10000);
  return x;
}
```

Again, multiplication by an odd number modulo a power of two is bijective, and addition modulo a power of two is also bijective.  Throwing these two additional operations in there effectively extends the hash and perturbs its behaviour according to `username_hash`.  And the outer loop keeps the result below 10000.

I'm not sure if you mean to limit the total number of users to 10000, or if you're going to keep separate counts for each contended username, but if you pass to `f()` that number (guaranteed to be less than 10000) along with some integer hash of the username to configure the operation, then you'll get a number out that's just as unique as the number you pass in.

Comment: I don't understand how this hash function guarantee that there is no collision. This is important as per pjs comment on the generalized birthday problem. If collisions are possible with the hash function, selecting a random number would be just as efficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: If `x` input has no collision, then the result has no collision.  Each and every step is bijective.

Comment: @JeanAlexandre, is this better?

Comment: Thanks, I understand much better now! But I've already used the code from my comment on Rossum's answer. Thanks anyway :) !